# Azure Container Instance - Support for Hybrid Connection

Tags: azure, containers

We're looking for a way to run a Docker container that needs a connection to an On-Premise database. This was previously done using a Hybrid Connection with a Web App.

Does Azure Container Instances (suppose running on Windows) support Hybrid Connections similar to Web Apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, you need to deploy your container group into a VNet that has access to a VPN or ExpressRoute connection to your on premises systems.

More details can be found here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-vnet

At the time of writing, keep note this is only generally available in a small set of regions and in preview in others. Also take note of some of the other configuration limitations. Though I expect these will change over time.

Comment: What I like about the Hybrid Connection is that I don't have to deal with complex firewall rules and related issues, I think VNets are not as easy to setup as a Hybrid Cnx

Comment: At this time this is the only approach to achieve a hybrid connection with ACI, not clear if they will release HCM support for ACI

Answer (score 1):

Windows containers in web apps do not support hybrid connection.

As Alex stated the only way to achieve this will be with ACI on a vNet and connecting to on prem through Express Route or VPN. This will only be possible with Linux containers, Windows ACI does not support vNet join.

Comment: Are the containers able to communicate with the hybrid connection directly (similar to a normal web app deployment)?

Comment: Hybrid Connection only supports Windows App Service, so unlikely to work running as a container.

Comment: @AlexMoore my initial thought was that windows containers for web apps would allow this, just had chance to test it and it does not

Comment: Thanks for the extra info